# If I reassign a variable which stores an rxjs subscription, does that unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here's a prototype of my code in Angular:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { SomeClass, SomeOtherClass } from './my-component.model.ts';
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})
export class AnalysisToolsComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private sub: Subscription;
    // instance of some class I defined in my models which has an event emitter
    instance = new SomeClass();

    // this function might get called more than once
    someFunction() {
        sub = this.instance.onEvent.subscribe( () => {})
    }

    // some other function which results in a reassignment of instance to maybe some other class
    someOtherFunction() {
        instance = new SomeOtherClass();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.sub) {
            this.sub.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Someone might ask why I'm reassigning the sub. It's basically because I have a child component which is a tool bar where only one tool can be selected at a time. So I only need one sub at a time to listen to events from interactions with the toolbar.

Should I be unsubbing each time I switch tool? Or can I just reassign the `sub` variable? My hypothesis is that the former is true. So might be nice to also get the explanation behind it if you have the answer.

Comment: Do you only need to resubscribe to `this.instance.onEvent` when `this.instance` gets reassigned? Or why is `someFunction()` being called multiple times?

Comment: @fridoo To answer your first question yes. And because you're asking, the detail I omitted here is that I have a JS dict with multiple classes, and I don't reinstantiate, I just change which one is the "selected" one. I don't want subs piling up each time the user selects a different tool, because if they do a lot of switching there could be many. So the `someFunction()`, is really `switchTool()`. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to a new Observable and automatically unsubscribing from the old one is best done with `switchMap`. To unsubscribe from an Observable when the Component gets destroyed use the takeUntil-destroy pattern.

```ts
tool$ = new BehaviorSubject<SomeTool>(new SomeTool());
private destroy$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.tool$.pipe(
    // use switchMap to map to a new onEvent Observable and unsubscribe from the old one
    switchMap(tool => tool.onEvent),
    // use takeUntil pattern to unsubscribe from tool$ when the component gets destroyed 
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)  
  ).subscribe( () => {} )
}

switchTool() {
  // supply a new Observable or Object containing an Observable to your Subject
  this.tool$.next(new SomeOtherTool());  // presuming SomeOtherTool extends SomeTool
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can unsubscribe something like below,

```
private sub: Subscription[] = [];

...
this.sub.push(this.instance.onEvent.subscribe( () => {}));
...

ngOnDestroy() {
  // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
  this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
}
```

> can I just reassign the sub variable?

It's not needed with this approach

It will **`unsubscribe()`** all the `subscriptions` held by the **[`Subscription`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html)**.

Comment: thanks. no luck finding the push method here https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subscription. Do you know where I can get an understanding of what exactly it does?

Comment: Sorry, just realised it's just an array of subscriptions. If the users hangs around on the page for a while and goes in and out of tools won't subscriptions just pile up then?

Comment: no, actually it will clear the subscriptions when ever component is going to destroy and creates new Array of them if you came abck again...

Comment: ```this.sub.foreach(sub=>sub.unsubscrbe())``` since when array has a unsubscribe metho

Answer (score -1):

Are all of these observables being created in the component? If so then when the component is destroyed then all the properties fall into garbage collection with it. You get memory leaks from subscription to observables that are not garbage collected at the same time the component is destroyed.

If your component instantiates an observable and nothing else is holding a reference to that observable then unsubscribing is unnecessary as the observable falls into garbage collection with the component.

An observable that still has active references like in a service will cause memory leaks if your component is still subscribed and the component cannot be garbage collected as the subscriptions are still active on the observable in the service.

Comment: Oh so you're saying that as long as I *don't* assign the subscription to a variable, it will eventually be garbage collected even if I don't explicitly make it happen with `unsubscribe()`. And then if I *do* assign the subscription to a variable I need to unsub. So then does that mean that if I *reassign* the variable which holds the subscription, everything but the last subscription will be garbage collected?

Comment: It is about is anything still holding a reference to the observable, not the subscriptions. Subscriptions is so you can break the link between the subscriber and the observable. But if the subscriber and observable both fall into garbage collection at the same time then unsubscribing doesn't matter.

Comment: If you create the observable in the component then as the component is destroyed then nothing is holding a reference to the observable. If a service created the observable a reference to the observable still exists in the service after the component is destroyed so you must unsubscribe so the service is not keeping the component from being garbage collected and firing any subscriptions if the observable emits.

Comment: I think I understand where you're going with this. Because I instantiated the `SomeClass` within the component and the `SomeClass` instantiated the `EventEmitter` (which is a type of `Observable`), that boils down to: I created the Observable in the component. Therefore I don't need to unsub. But if the observable was from another component, I'd need to unsub.